# Lists box manipulation on button click in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

Hello
I am doing a small I.T assignment where we have to create a database library type borrowing system and I have two list boxes listbox 1 is where all the games are listed and you can chose to borrow them the other one is where the games go to after you click the button that transfers them to listbox 2.

Aso how can I add a button that when you click it adds a new Item (game) to the first listbox and so you can borrow that one two

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Beaudean, do you have any code written yet so that we can point you in the right direction? If you read the FAQ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) it well explain that no one is going to provide you the from scratch code for this project.  However, if you have code you are working with we can help.

Comment: I have found your problem: 'School' doesn't have a 'k' in it.

Comment: Why are school assignmnets completely impractical from the UX point of view and nothing like anything you'd ever have to create in the real life?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two list boxes (listbox1 and listbox2) and a command button (cmd1) on a VB 6 form named Form1

```
private sub Form_Load()
    listbox1.AddItem "game 1"
    listbox1.AddItem "game 2"
    listbox1.AddItem "game 3"
end sub
Private Sub cmd1_click ()
    If listbox1.listindex >-1 then
        'Add the selected item from listbox1 to list box 2        
        listbox2.AddItem listbox1.List(listbox1.ListIndex)
        'Remove selected item from  listbox1
        listbox1.removeitem(listbox1.listindex)
    End If
End Sub
```